# Index match in VBA referencing a table

Tags: excel, vba, match

I want to update a line in my table based on a cell in another sheet, and to that end I intend to use the index match function. When I run the code below I get the error that it cannot get the property of the match function class.
What is the correct syntax in this regard?

```
Sub Update_Customer()

' Declarations
Dim rng as listobject
Dim wf as application.worksheetfunction
Dim cs_sht as string
Set rng = Sheets(1).ListObjects("Table_Customer")
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
cs_sht = ws.Name

' ERROR RUNNING THIS LINE vvvvv
wf.Index(rng.ListColumns("Firstname"), wf.Match(cs_sht, rng.ListColumns("Customer ID"), 0)) = ws.Range("C_Firstname").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Does it work with *wf* changed to *application.worksheetfunction*? I think the declaration should be`Dim wf as New application.worksheetfunction`.

Comment: You don't need `wf`. Just `With Application.WorksheetFunction`... weird that the error you're getting isn't error 91, because the `wf` reference is never `Set` (assigned) - but I don't think you could `New` up the `WorksheetFunction` class if you tried (similar to how you can't just `New` up a `Worksheet`).

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, yes it was the **Set** issue I was trying to get at but I didn't have a chance fof a full sandbox and thought adding *New* could be a fix. My bad.

Comment: You don't need `wf`, it's just a useless local copy of a global object. Just use the global one instead. `With Application.WorksheetFunction` ... `End With`.

Comment: I'd warmly recommend renaming that `ListObject` variable something like `table`, or  `customerTable`, or even `customers` - `rng` looks very much like it's a `Range`, and it isn't.

Comment: I had `Set wf = worksheetfunction` in another module but forgot to include it here, hence it didn't return an error. Adding the `DataBodyRange` along with the `With application.worksheetfunction` .. `End with` returns error `1004: Method range of object worksheet failed`

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do? If the function worked, it would return a `Variant` with the value at the index/match position - say that's `42`. What's `42 = ws.Range("C_Firstname").Value` supposed to be doing?

Comment: I want the part `ws.Range("C_Firstname").value` to overwrite the value in the table matching based on the customer ID. I.e. if the first name changes I can update the table to match the new name from my worksheet (`ws`). First name is just an example. Also the customer ID is the same as `cs_sht` as the sheet is named according to the customer ID.

Comment: If you need to write to a cell, you need a reference to that cell. The result of an `INDEX` worksheet function doesn't give you that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel functions need to be nested, because a cell's value needs to be parsed as a single step.

VBA code doesn't need to do that. VBA instructions work best and are easier to debug when you split them and make them do as little work as possible.

So instead of this:

```
wf.Index(rng.ListColumns("Firstname"), wf.Match(cs_sht, rng.ListColumns("Customer ID"), 0))
```

Split it up:

```
Dim matchResult As Long
matchResult = WorksheetFunction.Match(cs_sht, rng.ListColumns("Customer ID").DataBodyRange, 0)

Dim indexResult As Variant
indexResult = WorksheetFunction.Index(rng.ListColumns("FirstName").DataBodyRange, matchResult)
```

Note that you'll get a run-time error if either function fails to find what it's looking for. Use `On Error` to handle that case:

```
    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    Dim matchResult As Long
    matchResult = WorksheetFunction.Match(...)

    ...

    Exit Sub

CleanFail:
    MsgBox "Could not find record for '" & cs_sht & "'." & vbNewLine & Err.Description
End Sub
```

Get rid of `wf`. There's no use to copy object references of objects that are already global. The fewer global variables you use, the better.

> *if the first name changes I can update the table to match the new name from my worksheet*

You can't just assign the `indexResult` to a new value. The `indexResult` isn't holding a reference to any cell, it's just the result of the `INDEX` worksheet function. You need to use that result to *get* the cell you want to modify:

```
Dim targetCell As Range
Set targetCell = rng.ListColumns("FirstName").DataBodyRange.Cells(indexResult)
targetCell.Value = ws.Range("C_Firstname").Value
```

Comment: Thank you. When I execute the code I receive the clean fail error. In my particular case it fails to find `106` in the list of customer ID's but I can confirm it is on the list and still reports the failure to get the property of the Match function.

Comment: Watch for leading/trailing spaces, and - oh, it's a numeric value... not a string. `Match` will not find `106` when you're looking for `"106"`. Give the `Match` function the converted value: `Application.Match(CLng(cs_sht), ...`

Comment: I followed your advice but removed the line `Dim indexResult As Variant
indexResult = WorksheetFunction.Index(tbl_cs.ListColumns("Fornavn").DataBodyRange, matchResult)` and changed `Set targetCell = tbl_cs.ListColumns("Fornavn").DataBodyRange.Cells(indexresult)` to `Set targetCell = tbl_cs.ListColumns("Fornavn").DataBodyRange.Cells(matchResult)` and now it works. thanks! (I renamed my listobject, too)